# Unexpected token in react-native-video

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wanted to add a video player in my app, so I did `yarn add react-native-video` after adding the `<Video/>` running `yarn start` I have this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/jimmy/Desktop/projects/Video-Player/node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js: Unexpected token (78:24)

  76 |   };
  77 |
> 78 |   save = async (options?) => {
     |                         ^
  79 |     return await NativeModules.VideoManager.save(options, findNodeHandle(this._root));
  80 |   }
  81 |`
```

What can I do to solve that?

Comment: If you need to make changes to node_modules then make use of 'patch-package'.

Comment: can you please add the code of your Video Player js file.

Comment: It looks like you have not declared your `save` method properly. Declare your `save` method like this: `const save = async (options) => { // method code };`.  However please add related code to the question so it helps to understand the problem properly.

Comment: `onBuffer(){
  console.log('onBuffer')
 }

 videoError(){
  console.log('videoError')
 }

<View>
  <Video source={{uri: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sg_C-fGCHCE"}}   
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       }}                                      
       onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                
       onError={this.videoError}               
       style={styles.backgroundVideo} />.
        </View>`

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 : Open `/Users/jimmy/Desktop/projects/Video-Player/node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js`

STEP 2 : Replace `async (options?)` in line: 78 with `async (options)`

Comment: i did that, now i am having another error, 
`ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource' in '/Users/jimmy/Desktop/projects/Video-Player/node_modules/react-native-video'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js 38:0-81 353:19-37
 @ ./src/components/VideoPlayer/index.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./dist/input/runtime.js
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.`

Comment: `ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource' in '/Users/jimmy/Desktop/projects/Video-Player/node_modules/react-native-video'
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js 38:0-81 353:19-37
 @ ./src/components/VideoPlayer/index.js
 @ ./index.js
 @ ./dist/input/editor.j` now this error

Comment: Please share React Native version and the version of react-native-video